# Running Python script in Power BI as data source

Tags: python, powerbi

I have question on my python script, I'm using python script as data source to Power BI.
Trying to use DHL API to track shipments here.
Scripts runs and  connects but no values table is empty. What do i missing here? I'm fairly new and trying to play with code but unsuccessful yet.[Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCxc6.png)

Comment: Why bother with the Python integration when Power BI already has much more powerful webscaping tools built in, see [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents). Search "Power BI get data from REST API"

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for feedback. Can you provide sample code? I have tried using web.contents and keep telling me that credentials  not correct. = Web.Contents("https://api-test.dhl.com/track/shipments/get", [ApiKeyName="api-key"])